# How to find integration with Unknown

Tags: integration, limits

I am given the following problem which I have problem to know where to even start:

- The question: $\lim_{x\to 0}
  \frac{\int_0^x\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{a+2t^5}}dt}
  {bx-esinx}=\frac{1}{\pi}$
- The part where I will like to know where to start: 
  $\int_0^x\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{a+2t^5}}dt$

I appreciate suggestions on how I may get about solving the integration part before I move on to solve the limit question as a whole.

Comment: You need to find $b$ and $e$ or ? What's the question ?

Comment: The question states that $a$, $b$ and $e$ are constants. But we only need to find the value of $a$. Sorry for leaving that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to evaluate the integral.

Simply use L'Hopitals Rule. Integral will vanish on taking derivative.

For taking derivative w.r. t. $x$, use Leibnitz Integral Rule.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By the way, is it possible to guide me how to get rid of the integration part?

Comment: @Kyler Have you heard about L'Hopitals Rule? It's used to evaluate limits by taking derivative.

Comment: Yes, I do it is applied when there is a case of $\frac{0}{0}$. However, I have problems applying L'Hopitals Rule with Leibnitz Rule...

Comment: I have tried, is this correct?  $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{a+2t^5}}dt = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{a+2x^5}}$

Comment: @Kyler Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @Kyoer can you evaluate the limit now?

Comment: I have a problem, during the next step, I sub $x = 0$ to $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{a+2x^5}}$ and my answer to the limit becomes $0$. This is because my denominator becomes $b - ecosx$ and there is no need for Hopital Rule anymore. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) is enough here.

Comment: @Kyler Yes there is a little problem. The limit is **given** to you to be $\frac 1\pi$, so the limit cannot be $0$. Since the limit is finite and non-zero, you can conclude that $b$ has to be equal to $e$. Unless, the limit will become $0$. And if $b=e$, then there is indeterminacy again, of the kind $\frac 00$. Can you proceed again? (Use $1-\cos x= 2\sin^2 \left( \frac x2 \right)$, and simplify further.)

Comment: The $limit$ is derived after using L’Hopital the third time. I got $a = 5.3$. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Kyler Welcome :) Glad I could help!

Comment: @KylerWong: how did you get $a=5.3$? As far my answer shows you should get $a$ in terms of $b$.

Comment: After the first time I used L'Hopital, I got $b-ecosx$. After that, as mentioned by @JaideepKhare, I take $b=ecosx$. Therefore, I got $b-ecosx=e(1-cosx)$. I might have mentioned incorrectly that $e$ is a constant. It actually refers to exponent value. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

If $b\neq e$ then dividing the numerator and denominator by $x$ we can see that the limit is $0$ instead of $1/\pi$. Hence we must have $b=e$ and these constants must be non-zero and thus using $(x-\sin x) /x^3\to 1/6$ we see that the given condition implies $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^3}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{a+2t^5}}\,dt=\frac{b}{6\pi}\tag{1}$$ Further note that $a>0$ so that the integral makes sense at $t=0$. If $x>0$ then we have for $0<t<x$ $$\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{a+2x^5}}\leq \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{a+2t^5}}<\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{a}}$$ and integrating this with respect to $t$ on $[0,x]$ we get $$\frac{1}{3\sqrt{a+2x^5}}<\frac{1}{x^3}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{a+2t^5}}\,dt<\frac{1}{3\sqrt{a}}$$ and thus by Squeeze Theorem the limit $(1)$ is equal to $3/\sqrt{a}$ and thus from $(1)$ we have $9/a=b^2/36\pi^2$ so $a$ is determined in terms of $b=e$.